# result of call warning - want to use the result?

Tags: swift3

I have some difficulties with the new Swift 3.0.  First I know the “result of call is unused” warning has been debated a few times already. I have read the topics in question and usually the suggested answer is to use @discardableResult or using _ = before the function. But in my case this isn’t working. Before upgrading xCode the code worked great. I tested it on my iPad and everything was ok. But then once I upgraded xCode and had to convert the code to comply with Swift 3.0 the problem appeared.

The thing is that whatever I do, the object in the game isn’t showing as it should. Like I said, previously it worked, but now it doesn’t anymore. When the character runs into the object and it crashes it, the game should display a crashed object, but instead it shows an image with a red “X” as if the image isn’t there.

Here is the code. I would appreciate any suggestion you guys have. Thanks in advance

```
            for block in Blocks
        {
            block.move()
            block.isColB()
            if(block.manager.HasFloorL2)
            {
                if(block.isOnL2())
                {
                    if(block.manager.FloorL2Obstact)
                    {
                        block.ObsColL2() // here, result of call to ObscColL2() is unused
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(block.manager.HasFloorL1)
            {
                if(block.isOnL1())
                {
                    if(block.manager.FloorL1Obstact)
                    {
                        block.ObsColL1() // here, result of call to ObscColL1() is unused
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the function it refers to.

```
    func ObsColL1() -> Bool
{
    if(kong.Node.position.x+kong.Node.size.width*0.7 > self.holder.position.x+ObstacleL1.Node.position.x
        && kong.Node.position.x+kong.Node.size.width*0.7 < self.holder.position.x+ObstacleL1.Node.position.x+ObstacleL1.Node.size.width*0.3)
    {
        if(kong.Y() <= self.holder.position.y+(ObstacleL1.Node.position.y)+ObstacleL1.Node.size.height*0.7 && kong.Y() >= self.holder.position.y+ObstacleL1.Node.position.y)
        {
            if(kong.state != heroStates.flash && !self.ObstacleL1.crashed)
            {
                kong.Node.position.x = self.holder.position.x+ObstacleL1.Node.position.x-(kong.Node.size.width*0.55)
                kong.Node.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: self.holder.position.y+ObstacleL1.Node.position.y+ObstacleL1.Node.size.height/2, duration: 0.5))
                kong.die()
            }
            else
            {
                ObstacleL1.crash()
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

EDIT:
before and after
[before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKMr4.png)
[before and after 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWFfI.png)

Comment: The "unused return value" warning will have no impact on the functionality of your code. This means that the reason your image isn't display correctly is somewhere else. We would need to know a lot more about what's going on in your code to be able to help. If you have this in version control, if you could show a diff of the code before and after your swift 3 conversion, we might be able to help you spot the problem.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots. Did you mean these screenshots? Because the code didnt change much here.

Comment: You can declare your method as `@discardableResult func`

Comment: or just assign the Bool result to a var `let success = block.ObsColL1(); print(success)`\ or put it in an if conditional `if block.ObsColL1() {`  and the code to execute there if successful